# Understanding MIPS

Tags: programming, processing

I have a class where I'm learning MIPS and I have the following MIPS code:

```
.text
.globl main
main:
li $2, 5           
syscall                 
addu $8, $0, $2          
ori $2, $0, 5           
syscall                  
addu $9, $0, $2         
bgt $9, $8, L1
addu $10, $8, $9
ori $11, $0, 0
beq $0 $11 L2
L1:
addu $10, $0, $8    
L2:
addu $4, $0, $10         
ori $2, $0, 1            
syscall                  
ori $2, $0, 10           
syscall
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand what this code does?

Comment: What have you done to figure it out? What parts are confusing to you?  We're not going to do your homework for you.  (Also, this is probably a better fit for Stack Overflow - MIPS may be relegated to the embedded world these days, but this question is about programming in general.)

Comment: This would definitely fit StackOverflow much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the $X are just registers, think of them as variables if you're familiar with a higher level language. Then see [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/Mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) for what all of the syscalls do. Lastly, any of the things with colons after such as `L1:` are just labels. They mark code sections that you can branch to. As far as writing your own code, I recommend using the letters for register names rather than the numbers because your code will be much more readable.